# Javascript timer in the background

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a working count up timer but it resets everytime I change the page, for example `index.php -> help.php -> index.php`(and here the timer starts again from 0 instead of counting in the background)

The code is here:

```
<h1 id="demo"></h1>

countDownDate = new Date(); localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
var countDownDate = localStorage.getItem('startDate');
if (countDownDate) {
    countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate);
} else {
    countDownDate = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
}
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = now - countDownDate.getTime();

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Pass the timer value in session or cookie.

Comment: Could you help me a little bit more with that? I have never tried what you said

Comment: You don’t need an actual server-side session or a cookie here, storing this information client-side using localstorage is fine. But you are setting `countDownDate` to the current date every time, before you even check if a different value was already stored in localstorage. Of course you have to reverse the order here - check if a value exists first, and only if not initialize with the current date. (So basically that first line needs to be removed, apart from that you seem to already be doing things in the right order after that.)

Comment: Thank you, that did work! :)